# http request body parsing results in high cpu consumption

Tags: java, performance, http, netty, vert.x

I am seeing an issue with higher than expected CPU consumption due to request body processing. 
 My simple [application](https://github.com/whitingjr/vertx-perf/blob/variable-body-server/src/main/java/io/vertx/perf/web/RouterHttpVariableBodySize.java) is built using vertx-web. It accepts a POST request, asserting the body length matches the content length header.
 This application is being benchmarked with 2 HTTP operations using a [driver](https://github.com/RedHatPerf/faban-vertx-driver/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jboss/vertx/perf/driver/PacketDistributionDriver.java). The first sends 1k and the second sends 8k. Each once per 1000 millis. The body being just text.

During benchmarking I've found stackdumps showing multiple threads are in the same method

**io.netty.handler.codec.http.multipart.HttpPostStandardRequestDecoder.parseBodyAttributes**

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

To investigate further I attached JFR to the server process and re-ran the benchmark.
 The JFR shows the Netty method **parseBodyAttributes** is the 93.5% of sampled methods.

HTOP shows two cores very nearly pinned at 100%.

[image]

Has the method been seen to perform like this before ?

Comment: Setting the content type helped explain the overhead.  Using "application/json" bypasses the parsing. Whereas "multipart/form-data" needs to be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Going back and checking the load driver configuration showed the amount of bytes to be different to provided in initial comment. Instead of 1k it was 1024k and 8192k. This starts to explain the level of parsing activity with multipart/form-data content.